# How can I Knit a R Markdown file that contain data from another R Markdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Since I'm working with a huge Excel file and to avoid having an unnecessary giant and messy R Markdown file, I've decided to do all the necessary filters in a specific R Markdown file that only contain scripts related to my data modeling. I named this file as "filters.Rmd" and I created another R Markdown file called "plots.Rmd", that it only contains scripts related to the graphs' construction.

I can run all the chunks of "plots.Rmd" without any problem, even using data and values generated in "filters.Rmd". But when I try to Knit "plots.Rmd" it returns an error saying that the data weren't found.

How can I do this communication between those files? They are in the same project directory.

Comment: Please try a file with 2 commands : `rmarkdown::render("document.Rmd", envir = globalenv())`. If not working you can probably save a rdata in the first document and read it in the second one.

Comment: Consider moving most of the code out of the rmarkdown files and then calling it using `knitr::read_chunk()` or better still the `drake` package

Comment: It worked, I just had to add "encoding="UTF-8"" to it